# How to encapsulate Play's Status in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Multiple times throughout my code I use the following pattern to recover a failing future:

```
myFuture.recover {
        case t =>
          Logger.error(s"foo bar foo, exception: ${t.getMessage}.")
       InternalServerError(views.html.error(request, Messages("error.foo")))
      }
```

I am now looking for a way to encapsulate this behavior in order to remove code duplication. I tried to wrap it in a class but strangely, I cannot resolve `InternalServerError` inside the `apply` method.

```
class MyError(t: Throwable, logMsg: String, message: String) {
  def apply(t: Throwable, logMsg: String, message: String) = {
    Logger.error(logMsg)
  InternalServerError(views.html.error(request, message))
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can solve this? Also how do I go about the `request` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code Reuse**

Use `implicit class` to extend the functionality of the `Future` and put the `implicit class` inside the `package object` or object. Import the package object/object and use the code whenever you need it.

```
object common {
 implicit class FutureUtils(future: Future[Result]) {
  def graceful(implicit req: Request, msg: String): Future[Result] = {
    future.recover { case th =>
      import play.api.mvc.Results._
      Logger.error(logMsg)
      InternalServerError(views.html.error(request, message))
    }
  }
 }
}


import common._

class Foo extends Controller {
  def bar = Action { implicit req => 
    myFuture.graceful(Messages("foo.bar"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like that solution. However, that code does not compile on my box. I get the following error: `identifier expected but 'implicit' found.`.

Comment: @JohnDoe you got to create a `package object`

Comment: This is a nice solution, but you are advised to use implicits judiciously as it can complicate your code greatly.

Comment: @JohnDoe ... Please check now

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure you meant the `apply` method to be part of the companion object, not the class itself.

As for the resolution problem, you'll have to import it like this:

```
object MyError {
  def apply(t: Throwable, logMsg: String, message: String, request: Request): Result = {
    import play.api.mvc.Results._
    Logger.error(logMsg)
    InternalServerError(views.html.error(request, message))
  }
}
```

Then you can do

```
MyError(t, "log something", "message", request)
```

as the last line inside a controller `Action`